# Subprocess Run/Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I have that command in Linux :

`host -t soa 88.17.156.in-addr.arpa | cut -d' ' -f6 | sed 's/\./\@/' | sed 's/\.$//'`

I trying put this command in python and read but I have only errors? Rly I don't know where would be problem :
COMMAND :

```
mail = subprocess.run(["host","-t","soa",reverse_domain,"|","cut","-d' '","-f6","|","sed","'s/\./\@/'","|","sed","'s/\.$//'"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        result_mail = str(mail.stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

Error():

```
host: couldn't get address for ' |': not found
CompletedProcess(args=['host', '-t', 'soa', '3.4.17.156.in-addr.arpa', ' |', 'cut', "-d' '", '-f6', '|', 'sed', "'s/\\./\\@/'", '|', 'sed', "'s/\\.$//'"], returncode=1, stdout=b'')
```

@edit It is with shell=False, when I used shell=True error is like command in linux "man host" didn't see everything 
Thanks :)

Comment: The pipe character **|** is not part of the subprocess. You need to have Python `subprocess` generate the pipe from one `subprocess` to the next. I do not understand what you mean with `shell=True` did not work, though? (However, it may be dangerous to use this construct. Consult the manual.)

Comment: That commend working :             `mail = subprocess.run(["host -t soa 88.17.156.in-addr.arpa | cut -d' ' -f6 | sed 's/\./\@/' | sed 's/\.$//'"],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        result_mail = str(mail.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
        print(result_mail)`  and the result is e-mail. If I exange IP adres to +reverse_domain+ nothing working

Comment: What is stored in `reverse_domain`? And what is the error message when "nothing working"?

Comment: `host = subprocess.run(['host','-t','soa',str_IP], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        result_host = str(host.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
        reverse_domain = result_host[0:23]` -> reverse domain. In "nothing working" console shows something like "man host" linux cmd

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand. Please update your question with the failing case, the exact error message and the expected result.